# Gitlab Job failed keeps failing during "prepare environment" since it cannot link container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Docker build job keeps failing with below error:

**"ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-3fjcetbw-project-36861-concurrent-0-8c1f412098c40e0b-docker-0 AS /runner-3fjcetbw-project-36861-concurrent-0-8c1f412098c40e0b-predefined-0/docker (exec.go:73:0s). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information"**

any idea on this?

**Edit 2:** I got it working in specific runner, now the question is why is it not working in a shared runner

This is the guide I followed: https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/customer-success/professional-services-engineering/education-services/gitlabcicdhandsonlab8.html

Here's the .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stages:
    - test
    - build

variables: 
    INLINE_GLOBAL_VARIABLE: "I'm an inline variable set at the global level of the CI/CD configuration file"

test job:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "I am a unit test!"

build job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "I am a build image!"

environment echoes:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Who am I running as..."
    - whoami
    - echo "Where am I..."
    - pwd
    - ls -al
    - echo "Here's what is available in our environment..."
    - env

environment variables:
  stage: build
  variables:   
   INLINE_LOCAL_VARIABLE: "I'm an inline variable set at the job level of the CI/CD configuration file"
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "Here are some default, global, & local variables..."
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - echo $group_level_variable
    - echo $project_level_variable
    - echo $INLINE_GLOBAL_VARIABLE
    - echo $INLINE_LOCAL_VARIABLE

build image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:18
  services:
    - docker:18-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  script:
    - echo $IMAGE
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE .
    - docker push $IMAGE
```

[image: gitLab failed job]

**Edit 1:** The job is using a shared runner provided by gitlab
[image: Project Runners]

**Edit 2:** A specific runner seems to be working.

config.toml of the runner

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "AMD-PC"
  url = "https://spt.gitlabtraining.cloud/"
  id = 4316
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-03-04T04:09:18Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/certs/client"]
    shm_size = 0
```

prior values

```
privileged = false
volumes = ["/cache"]
```

[image: Specific runner results]

Comment: It looks like you're using a self-hosted runner. Have you [configured your runner for docker in docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker)?

Comment: @sytech, the job is using a shared runner provided by gitlab, i have attached the screenshot of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace build image job with below fixes this

```
build image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.17
  services:
    - docker:20.10.17-dind
  variables:
    IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker --version
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $IMAGE .
    - docker push $IMAGE
```

For some reason version 18, is throwing an error

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com/-/merge_requests/121189#note_1308494287